# How do I add a string variable to a android R.string resource

Tags: android, string, kotlin, string-resource

I Have string resource var `textId: Int =  R.string.my_specific_string` and i want to add a changing string `var changingString: String = "hello"` to it, because I then want to use that new `textId` elsewhere. How do I do this? something like textId = textId + changingString ...should then equal `println textId //"My specific String hello"`

Comment: show some code from your app

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to manually convert the resource ID to a String to be able to combine it with other Strings. So in an Activity it would look like this:

```
private var textId: Int =  R.string.my_specific_string
private var changingString = "hello"

private val combinedString: String
    get() = getString(textId) + changingString
```

Note that this last property is `val`, not `var` because there’s no way for it to have a sensible setter—its value is based on other properties. In this case `val` means read-only, not immutable. A custom getter like this is reevaluated every time the property is accessed, so it will have the new value each time you use it.

If you’re in a fragment, put `requireContext().` before `getString`.

Depending on how you’re using this, format strings may be more appropriate. I suggest reading up on “Android resource format strings” to see if it’s more applicable to your use case.